# How many constructors need to be specified for derived class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor

i try to learn Object oriented programming and have a basic question.
There is a base class A which has three constructors taking either 0, 1 and 2 variables.
I want to derive a class B out of A where i want to pass up to three variables optionally. 
So i need at least three different constructors for B, one for each optional variable. 
But do i also need three different constructors for B for every constructor of base class A, namely 9 constructors in total?

Comment: Why would you?? And how would these constructors look like then?

Comment: It all depends on what you are trying to achieve, so without any code you can't really give this a straight answer, but needing 9 constructors would almost certainly be a design flaw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As constructors aren't inherited automatically that would be up to you.
You could, however, do something like this:

```
class A {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

public:
    A(int newA = 0, int newB = 0, int newC = 0): a(newA), b(newB), c(newC){}
};
class B : public A{
    using A::A;
};
```

This also includes optional parameters and constructor initializer lists, which should be pretty self-explanatory.
Hopes this answers your question.

Cheers